# Is there a way to use my Python code in a React Native app?

Tags: python, python-3.x, reactjs, react-native, flask

So I was assigned a Software Architecture Recovery Desktop App as a semester project. I did that pretty well using Python and the UI in PyQt5. Now, I am assigned to make a web app as well as a mobile app of the same project. For the web app, I am planning to use Python's Flask framework so that I just need to create the front end of the web app only. For mobile app, I am not sure what to do. I am a little familiar with React Native. Is there a way where I can use my Python Code in a React Native app. I want the UI to be made of React Native Components using Python code to perform various functions. Is this possible? Is there another suitable way? Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to make it running with the most least effort , you can do your webapp and easily you make an app with a single webview with your webapp url!

you are also able to inject extra features if you need.

[here is the link to RNWebview](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview)

Comment: I might try this.

Comment: that is the fastest and best way if you already have the webapp or you plan to make one.